# How do I import and read a file in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, import

This is sort of a part two for my text file exporting and importing dilemma. Right now, I have the write code and export code. The final pieces to the puzzle is import code and read code. I want to take an attachment from an email and import it into the app, so I can read it. I have the basic read code:

```
@IBAction func readButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let filePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("matrixFile.txt")
    do {
        try displayField.text = String(contentsOfFile: path!,
                                       encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    } catch let error as NSError{
        displayField.text = String(describing: error)
    }
}
```

But I was also wondering what filePath would be when importing. I adjusted the info.plist for exportation, but would I need to make any more changes to that? Here are my current additions:
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You wouldn't have a "read" button in your app. The user should choose to launch your app from the file attachment while viewing an email. iOS will then launch your app and the proper app delegate method will be called giving you the URL to the file.

Comment: @rmaddy This wasn't for my app, this was from a tester project I made for reading and writing files

Comment: If the user won't edit the text I recommend using QuickLook framework for displaying the text file to the user.

Comment: @LeoDabus the goal isn't to display it to the user, it's to take the data from the file ignorer to complete an operation.

Comment: Your question it is unclear. Where are you importing your text files from ? What changes have you made to your app info.plist ?

Comment: where is your file `"matrixFile.txt"` located ?

Comment: In the test program I added in my original thread, it was in documents. But for what I'm trying to do, the text file will be an attachment in mail. I added info.plist info to the main.

Answer (score 8):

In order for you to open a document coming in via e-mail attachment, you would need to have your application appear in the Open in ... menu list. As per the [relevant Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1587/_index.html) you have to:

> A: You need to register the document types that your application can
>   open with iOS. To do this you need to add a document type to your
>   app’s Info.plist for each document type that your app can open.
>   Additionally if any of the document types are not known by iOS, you
>   will need to provide an Uniform Type Identifier (UTI) for that
>   document type.

I know you have added the Exported Type UTI already (as shown in your screenshot) but did you follow the instructions on the above linked page to add a Document Type using the UTI you defined? If you didn't, you should add the Document Type as well since, I believe, it's the Document Type which identifies that your app as being able to handle that particular type of document.

Also, since txt is a known format, you probably don't need to define the UTI again for text files. You might be able to just use the existing UTI for text files in your Document Type definition.

In fact, I tested the above by creating a quick test app and all I had to add to the app was the Document Type, (without a UTI definition since text is a known type) in order for me to see my test app in the Open in... list. Here's my Document Type declaration:
[image]

**Update:**
As @LeoDabus mentions, you do need to implement actually opening the file via the `UIApplicationDelegate`'s `application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool` method. I figured you were aware of this part, but if you need additional help with this, do ask here and I'll respond.

Comment: This is only half way of what he is trying to do. You need also to implement the opening (displaying) or saving (moving) locally the external file

Comment: @LeoDabus I realize that but it looked as if he knew that part - he seemed to be stuck on getting the app in the Open In ... list - at least, that was my impression. Will add a note about what you said to my answer in case he needs further help.

Comment: @Fahim I would appreciate some additional help with this. I have mainly done backend work for this app and haven't worked with the app delegate yet.

Comment: @EthanRappaport Sure, where are you stuck? Once you get the Document Type set up, and implement `application:open:` you will get a URL to the file via the `url` parameter. Then, you simply need to handle displaying/opening the file as you originally did ...

Comment: How would I implement the `application:open:` method in the app delegate and send the URL back to the view controller?

Comment: That would depend on your app structure - if you have a direct reference to your view controller from your app delegate (for instance, if the view controller is your root view controller) you can directly call the method on the view controller. Or, you can simply post a notification from your app delegate that the view controller is observing and pass the URL via the notification.

Comment: @EthanRappaport the recommended way would be to first check the options property and get the .openInPlace key bool value and move the file if it is not true. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationopenurloptionsopeninplacekey you can also check the name of the sending app getting the .sourceApplication key string value and the .annotation key that contains a dictionary with the information passed to the UIDocumentInteractionController object’s annotation property.

Comment: @Fahim @LeoDabus I've worked on the system and got a way to pass the URL to the view controller, but instead of displaying the text, it says `("matrixFile.text", Unicode (UTF-8))`. What is going wrong?

Comment: The comments area is intended for comments not question. Feel free to open a new question with your code showing how you move the Item from the inbox to another directory. And explaining what it is not working.