# load text file from device storage into app in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift3, filesystems

I would like to load file from mobile device storage into my app, and I am unable to find a solution.

It should be like on load button it opens device storage and user will choose the file and use in application (Swift3)

Comment: it will be done easily if your saved file is in iCloud too. it can be done by piking files from the iCloud.

Comment: is it possible to have code example, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Apple gives direct access to file system in iOS. To import a file externally the user needs to initiate an 'Open With' option.

Check this out: [How do I import and read a file in my iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195134/how-do-i-import-and-read-a-file-in-my-ios-app)