# How can I import data into an iOS App without iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

Friends

I am developing an iOS app.

I need to import some data into it.

The data will be in a file on a computer, and using the Internet would be very inconvenient. (This rules out iCloud).  A USB cable or Air Drop would be perfect.

I cannot find any method to do this.  Strange, it must be a common task

I found this: [How do I import and read a file in my iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43195134/4326664) but it is about (a) initialising the process form outside the app and (b) about using  email

Comment: The answer to your linked question still applies to you. You need to specify that your app can open one or more types of files. That's it. Now if someone Airdrops a file, the receiving iOS device can offer to open the received file in any app that claims to handle the given file.

Comment: I have seven "Info.plist" files under the root of the project.  I think I can find the correct one.  <Project Name>/Info.plist.

Comment: An app only has one Info.plist. Why do you have 7?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75656618/cordova-ios-download-file-to-iphones-general-downloads-folder/75657360#75657360) - You can easily make it possible for users to save documents directly to your app's "documents" folder.  You can also use `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to enable your app to open files from a user specified cloud on on-device location

Comment: " An app only has one Info.plist. Why do you have 7? "  There seems to be one for each test, and two I cannot identify.  There is clearly one associated with the app, it is the one changed when I use the Xcode project settings

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that places the file on to the iPad where I can read it

I edited the appropriate `info.plist` file.  I added the following:

```
        <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Draft Layouts</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.comma-separated-values-text</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

and

```
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
```

and

```
    <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
    <true/>
```

Now when I use Air Drop to move a CSV file to the iPad my app shows up as a receiver

Inspecting the bundle I see it is placed in:

AppData/Documents/Inbox/MyFile.csv

I am unsure what changes I made to `info.plist` are necessary, or quite what they are all for.